# Atom doesn't display virtual environment

Tags: python, atom-editor, virtual-environment

I'm new to the programming world and i picked up python.

I'm doing some exercise and 1 requires me to use virtual environment. I have created the virtual environment and activated it as below 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysxeK.png)

I then opened atom from the activated virtual environment but atom doesn't seem to see the environment when I click on "no virtualenv"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMUIm.png)

Comment: I had faced a similar problem while using atom. This [link](https://atom.io/packages/virtualenv) did the trick back then. I'm not sure about how it works right now. Please do let me know if this helps.

Comment: hi I looked into the link and it didn't help much, i dont know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try closing atom and running ```atom --new-instance```. It worked in some cases. Also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207427/using-anaconda-environment-in-atom).