# Selecting a virtual env in atom from conda

Tags: python, conda, atom-editor

I am trying to become familiar with atom.io text editor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvSpZXT8XhU
The link shows a good example of activating a particular virtual environment of interest (skip to 12 minutes). This is done using the 'atom-python-virtualenv' package. However, they don't use anaconda to manage their virtual environments. I believe the path to their envs is different. Has anyone successfully been able to use the atom.io package 'atom-python-virtualenv' to list the same ones available via 'conda env list'?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using anaconda environment in Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207427/using-anaconda-environment-in-atom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your problem by doing this:

1. Activate your conda environment in the terminal
2. Run `atom --new-instance`