# atom - Could not locate an attribute

Tags: python, ssl, atom-editor, imaplib

I ve a problem with Atom text editor. I am trying to access `IMAP4_SSL` attribute in imaplib package:

```
import imaplib
...
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("some.mail.server")
```

Which raises the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'
```

I was trying to find cause for it. After trying the code above from conda prompt, the error was gone. So, I thought it should have something to do with the editor or "script" package of Atom. I checked `sys.path` and `sys.version` from Atom and there were no problems. `python.coffee` configuration below:

```
exports.Python =
  'Selection Based':
    command: 'python'
    args: (context) ->
      code = context.getCode()
      tmpFile = GrammarUtils.createTempFileWithCode(code)
      return ['-u', tmpFile]
```

Edit: And I think the package imported successfully, because I can access other attributes of it like `IMAP`

Edit2: Most probably my problem is related with the following prompt which I get when I launch python in Windows Powershell:

```
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

I've already tried to run `activate.bat` script but did not work out and please notice that Anaconda is installed into another drive with Windows. But the following path is already included in environment variables:

```
D:/anaconda
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If you look into [source for imaplib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/imaplib.py), you'll see that existence of IMAP4_SSL is conditional. Documentation says "to use this class you need a socket module that was compiled with SSL support". That's probably your problem

Comment: Yes yo are right indeed `print(imaplib.HAVE_SSL)` prints `False`

Comment: So the problem is importing `ssl` package I suppose
`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my answer was here and nothing was wrong with my conda environment

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49737729/7941061